# Closest cross-platform alternative to Direct2D/DirectWrite?

Tags: c++, graphics, direct2d, directwrite

What are some good cross-platform alternatives to Windows-specific 2D APIs? I'm looking for an API for rendering simple geometric objects as well as an API for rendering text with subpixel antialiasing (ClearType) and OpenType support, specifically support for hinting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) is the defacto cross-platform graphics API. OpenGL [supports the FreeType and OpenType libraries](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01). Newer versions of [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/subpixel-hinting.html) (2.7+) have support for sub-pixel hinting similar to what DirectWrite offers.

Comment: Apparently, OpenGL does not guarantee identical pixel output across implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Simple DirectMedia Layer (SDL)](http://libsdl.org), it contains exactly what you need. [SDL_ttf](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/) is an extension to libsdl that provides functionality for rendering of text.